# Access data from BoundField DataField

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

how would I access data from `<asp:BoundField DataField="DateStart"`.
I have an `IF` statement and I want to see if data is `>` or `<` than the data in the `DataField`.

I used to use `rows(0).findControl` but that wont work anymore.

```
If today > item.FindControl("btnSelect") And today < item.FindControl("btnSelect") Then
```

if its possible

Comment: Your comparison is pointless, isn't it? In your question you mention that you want to check _"if data is > or <"_. Then i would check if it's `<>`. If you want the opposite, as your code suggests using `And`, then it's even less useful since it's never true. A date cannot be both, earlier and later than today. Side-note: you should use `AndAlso` and `OrElse` instead of `And` and `Or` in general.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `FindControl` on  `BoundField`s, only with `TemplateFields`. You need to use the cell's [`Text` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.tablecell.text%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Dim text = grid.Rows(index).Cells(index).Text ' the cell-index is the column-index '
```

You need to parse it to `DateTime`/`Date`:

```
Dim dateStart = Date.Parse(text)
If Date.Today > dateStart.Date  ...
```

But if you use `RowDataBound` instead you can access the original [`DataItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.dataitem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). But then i need to know more to show you an example.

Answer (score 0):

In the definition of your GridView, add

```
<asp:GridView .... DataKeyNames="ItemID" ...>
```

You also need to use OnRowDataBound, not OnDataBound

```
<asp:GridView .... DataKeyNames="ItemID" ... OnRowDataBound="GridView_RowDataBound">
```

Then in your code behind, something like this

```
protected void GridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
     if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
     {
          int ItemId = Int32.Parse(YourGridView.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Values[0].ToString());
     }
}
```

If you want to find multiple value then set **DataKeyNames** as

`DataKeyNames="ID,Name,COde,Value and so on"`